# How to uninstall & remove postgres service in windows machine from services.msc [Microsoft Services management Console]

Tags: postgresql, service, windows-10, regedit

I had installed some specific software, with that, I have got Postgres also installed.

I had installed my application with demo data with that my application was not starting-up in `services.msc` wherein `postgres` services coming up and running properly.

As my application didn't work I had gone for uninstallation in "Apps & Features" in my Windows 10 Machine.

After uninstallation, I had observed that the services,- `postgres` and `my-app-service` weren't gone in the list of `services.msc`. I made them `disabled` in the option and gone for re-installation of my application. While doing re-installation the setup wizard says Postgres is already running with some database.

I had tried renaming the complete folder. However the same error I have got again.

Now my question is how to remove postgres service from `services.msc`. Maybe someone can guide how to do that via `regedit.exe` or so.

[image]

The main complaint from my-app is that Postgres data already exists. I believe if `postgres` service is removed from `services.msc`, then I hope I can do re-installation of my application.

Comment: There were another uninstaller as part of software distribution, with that I am able to remove `postgres` and one another `service` which is been accompanied.

Comment: You can either use Postgres' `pg_ctl unregister` or the build-in `sc` tool (`sc delete name_of_the_service`).

Comment: One other thing we did was, we had, removed concerned `%programdata%` been wiped off, for our application, in our `windows` system.

Answer (score 1):

- You've opened services.msc
- You've opened the particular service

In "Path to Executable". there is an -N option, like  `-N "postgresql-x64-9.6"`

Open a command prompt as Administrator (right click option)

`sc delete "postgresql-x64-9.6"`

If you get `[SC] DeleteService SUCCESS` then you are done.

If you get another message, you might have to restart the computer before trying again. Occasionally services get into compromised states, which require that reboot.